# Regarding pcie bus error

Tags: kernel

I'm receiving PCIe bus errors in `kern.log` of version 16, 18 and 19 of Ubuntu  when booting the system:

```
kernel: [ 13.231617] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
kernel: [ 13.231627] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer,
id=00e0(Receiver ID)
kernel: [ 13.231630] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
kernel: [ 13.231633] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: [ 0] Receiver Error (First)
```

I already avoided this error temporarily in kernel log by disabling  ASPM with the kernel parameter  `pcie_aspm=off`

*Is there a permanent solution to fix this PCIe bus error?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) in the kernel.  The only thing you can do is to await a newer kernel being distributed by Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) after Linus Torvalds' team gets to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable info